# Writing data in wrong location after appending three columns

Tags: c#, excel, vba, excel-interop

I copy the data from one location to another and am able to read and print all values and able to append three column in the Excel file. So now A, B, C column became D, E, F (Shifting), etc..

```
            Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbooks workbooks = app.Workbooks;
            string newlocation_filename = @"C:\Windows\Temp\" + FileName;
            File.Copy(FilePath, newlocation_filename, true);
            //string filename = FilePath;
            workbooks.Open(newlocation_filename);
            Excel.Workbook workbook = workbooks.Item[1];
            Excel.Sheets worksheets = workbook.Worksheets;
            Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)worksheets.Item[1];
            Excel.Range cells = worksheet.UsedRange;
            Range oRng = worksheet.Range["A1"];
           oRng.EntireColumn.Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight,XlInsertFormatOrigin.xlFormatFromRightOrBelow);

            oRng = worksheet.Range["B1"];
             oRng.EntireColumn.Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight,XlInsertFormatOrigin.xlFormatFromRightOrBelow);

            oRng = worksheet.Range["C1"];
            oRng.EntireColumn.Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight,XlInsertFormatOrigin.xlFormatFromRightOrBelow);

            cells[1, 1] = "AccountNumber";//Set value for row 1 and column 2 (A1)
            cells[1, 2] = "CustomerName";
            cells[1, 3] = "ComparisionResult";//Set value for row 1 and column 3 (B1)

            workbook.Save();//Save Excel-File
            app.Quit();

        }
```

From the above code `AccountNumber`,`CustomerName`, `ComparisionResult` are need to set in A1, B1, C1 cell (appended new columns) respectively. But 
 it replace the data in D1,E1,F1 (old A1, B1, C1 means before appending) field values and the A1, B1, C1 field values are not updating.  I think it replace the data and then appending is happening.

Any Update statement are required to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UsedRange` doesn't necessarily begin at A1, so if your used range was (eg) D1:F20 then `UsedRange.Cells[1,1]` is D1.

So, don't use `UsedRange` as the basis for `cells` if you want to reliably update fixed locations on the sheet.

Instead use something like:

```
 worksheet.Range["A1"] = "AccountNumber";
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have used only fixed location[1,1], [1,2], [1,3] like that. not used usedRange.cell[1,1].

Comment: can you please come back on this ?

Comment: You set `cells` = `worksheet.UsedRange`, so `cells[1,1]` is the top-left cell in *UsedRange*, and that is not *necessarily* the top-left cell in the worksheet.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. its working now... Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

Tim got it almost right, but strictly speaking, the problem is not exactly related to a wrong use of UsedRange, but to the insertions that happen later, which affect an already assigned range variable. You first assign:

```
Excel.Range cells = worksheet.UsedRange;
```

At this moment, `cells[1, 1]` is `A1`, because the latter is actually the first used cell. But when later you do three column insertions at the beginning, *any range* that you had set will move 3 positions to the right. So after the three insertions, `cells[1, 1]` is `D1`, not `A1`. This shift will apply to *any* range object, not only (but including) the `UsedRange`.

It is for this reason that `cells[1, 1] = "AccountNumber";` actually writes to `D1` instead of `A1`.

The solution is to shift back the range to compensate for the added insertions. You can add this line just before writing to cells:

```
cells = cells.Offset(0, -3);
cells[1, 1] = "AccountNumber";
// etc...
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Its is working now. Thank you for your reply A.S.H

Comment: Good call - I missed the insertion